# Twitter Bootstrap Popovers Misaligned with different sized content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, popover

I have created a custom binding for knockout for twitter bootstrap popovers and I am using that to display data with two way binding in a popover but if the size of the content is different between each popover the alignment is off

http://jsfiddle.net/billpull/g6vH2/1

I am not sure what the relevant code to post here would be so ill just post the entire thing check the fiddle for a demo.

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <br><br><br>
        <div data-bind="foreach: items">
            <span data-bind="text: label"></span>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: required" />
            <button data-bind="popover: {template: 'settingsPopover', trigger: 'click'}">settings</button><br>
        </div>
        <script type="text/html" id="settingsPopover">
            <h4><span class="icon-cog">&nbsp;</span> Attributes</h4>
            <label>Label</label>
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: label, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" />
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: required" /> Required
            </label>
            <ul data-bind="foreach: options">
                <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
            </ul>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
function s4() {
  return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
             .toString(16)
             .substring(1);
};
function guid() {
  return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
         s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
}

// Bind Twitter Popover
ko.bindingHandlers.popover = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var $element = $(element);
        // read popover options 
        var popoverBindingValues = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        // set popover title 
        var popoverTitle = popoverBindingValues.title;

        // set popover template id
        var tmplId = popoverBindingValues.template;

        // set popover trigger
        var trigger = popoverBindingValues.trigger;

        // get template html
        var tmplHtml = $('#' + tmplId).html();

        // create unique identifier to bind to
        var uuid = guid();
        var domId = "ko-bs-popover-" + uuid;

        // create correct binding context
        var childBindingContext = bindingContext.createChildContext(viewModel);

        // create DOM object to use for popover content
        var tmplDom = $('<div/>', {
            "class" : "ko-popover",
            "id" : domId
        }).html(tmplHtml);

        // set content options
        options = {
            content: tmplDom[0].outerHTML,
            title: popoverTitle
        };

        // Need to copy this, otherwise all the popups end up with the value of the last item
        var popoverOptions = $.extend({}, ko.bindingHandlers.popover.options, options);

        // bind popover to element click
        $element.bind(trigger, function (e) {
            $(this).popover(popoverOptions).popover('toggle');

            // if the popover is visible bind the view model to our dom ID
            if($('#' + domId).is(':visible')){
                ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(childBindingContext, $('#' + domId)[0]);
            }
        });

        // Also tell KO *not* to bind the descendants itself, otherwise they will be bound twice
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    },
    options: {
        placement: "right",
        title: "",
        html: true,
        content: "",
        trigger: "manual",
        container: 'body'
    }
};

var ItemModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.label = ko.observable(data.label);
    self.required = ko.observable(data.required);
    self.options = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(data.options, function(option) {
        return option;
    }));
}

var ViewModel = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.initItems = [
      {"label":"Item 1", "required": false, "options": [1,2,3,4,5,6]},
      {"label":"Item 2", "required": true, "options": [1,2,3]},
      {"label":"Item 3", "required": false, "options": []},
      {"label":"Item 4", "required": true, "options": [1,2,3,6]}
   ];

  self.items = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(self.initItems, function (item) {
      return new ItemModel(item);
  }));
};

$(function(){
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel);
 });
```

http://billpull.github.com/knockout-bootstrap/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gurkavcu/m9Axb/)

May be you can use ko.applyBindingsToNode() for this. First render the template then bind the popover.

```
$element.bind(trigger, function (e) {

    ko.applyBindingsToNode( tmplDom[0], {template : { name :'settingsPopover', data : viewModel}});            
    options = {
        content: tmplDom[0].outerHTML,
        title: popoverTitle
    };

    // Need to copy this, otherwise all the popups end up with the value of the last item
    var popoverOptions = $.extend({}, ko.bindingHandlers.popover.options, options);            
    $(this).popover(popoverOptions).popover('show');        
  //  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When You bind click to element in Your popover binding, You initialize bootstrap popover and then appply binding to descendants. That is why bootstrap popover calculates it's position incorrectly (there're no nested li-s yet so their height is zero). After that knockout appends li-s elements and popover height changes and You have to recalculate popover position.

After the next click You reinitialize bootstrap popover but do not apply bindings, this case popover position calculates correctly.

Comment: can you think of anyway to get around that since I dont know if I can apply the bindings before the popover has been created.

Comment: Unfortunately bootstrap and knockout are a little incompatible. Currently bootstrap replaces the popover content with html code on open, that's the place where knockout bindings are lost. Also open method contains ths position calculations, that's why You can't recalculate it separately after the popover.open and knockout binding applied. So I would suggest to rewrite bootstrap popover - either cut of the position calculation to the separate method and run it after knockout binding applied or ...

Comment: ... change the logic of popover so that open and hide methods only change the visibility of popover content without affecting the dom structure

Answer (score 0):

```
$element.bind(trigger, function (e) {

ko.applyBindingsToNode( tmplDom[0], {template : { name :'settingsPopover', data : viewModel}});            
options = {
    content: tmplDom[0].outerHTML,
    title: popoverTitle
};

// Need to copy this, otherwise all the popups end up with the value of the last item
var popoverOptions = $.extend({}, ko.bindingHandlers.popover.options, options);            
$(this).popover(popoverOptions).popover('show');        
//  }
});
```

The popover never closes for some reason!! :(